# Looping over key value object with underscore

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

I have several **arrays of string** and given a specific **input key** string I'm trying to return the corresponding key.

For example if the input value is 'a1' it should return 'aa' because 'a1' is part of the array values of key 'aa'.

```
 inputKey = 'a1';
 dict = {
    'aa': ['a1', 'a2'],
    'bb' : ['b1', 'b4', 'b6']
    ...
  };

  /
  // _.contains())
```

I was thinking of looping over each element in the dictionary and if the value exists in the array then return the key.

Is this the best way to go about doing this? (finding the corresponding key for an array of values) in other words (mapping down some specific values to another value).

Comment: Do you need to use underscore? It's just 1 line of vanilla javascript.

Comment: `Object.keys(dict).find(k => dict[k].some(d => d === inputKey));`

Comment: The vanilla js solution is just as easy, but if you have underscore available anyway, you can use it's `_.findKey` method if you like: `_.findKey(dict, v => v.includes(inputKey))`

Comment: Ah thank you, the vanilla javascript option is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you want an approach using `underscore`.

*This is an alternative using the function `find` and function `some`.*

```js
let inputKey = 'a1',
    dict = {      'aa': ['a1', 'a2'],      'bb': ['b1', 'b4', 'b6']    },
    result = Object.keys(dict).find(k => dict[k].some(d => d === inputKey));
    
console.log(result);
```

*Using the function includes*

```js
let inputKey = 'a1',
    dict = {      'aa': ['a1', 'a2'],      'bb': ['b1', 'b4', 'b6']    },
    result = Object.keys(dict).find(k => dict[k].includes(inputKey));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple enough with [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
let inputVal = 'a1';
let inputVal2 = 'b1';
let inputVal3 = 'c1';

let dict = {
  'aa': ['a1', 'a2'],
  'bb' : ['b1', 'b4', 'b6']
};

let foundKey = Object.keys(dict).find(key => dict[key].includes(inputVal));
let foundKey2 = Object.keys(dict).find(key => dict[key].includes(inputVal2));
let foundKey3 = Object.keys(dict).find(key => dict[key].includes(inputVal3));

console.log(foundKey);
console.log(foundKey2);
console.log(foundKey3);
```